# How can i subscribe a consumer and notify him of any changes in django channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm currently building an application that allows users to collaborate together and create things, as I require a sort of discord like group chatfeed. I need to be able to subscribe logged in users to a project for notifications.
I have a method `open_project` that retrieves details from a project that has been selected by the user, which I use to subscribe him to any updates for that project.

So I can think of 2 ways of doing this. I have created a instance variable in my connect function, like this:

```
def connect(self):
    print("connected to projectconsumer...")
    self.accept()
    self.projectSessions = {}
```

And here is the `open_project` method:

```
def open_project(self, message):

    p = Project.objects.values("projectname").get(id=message)
    if len(self.projectSessions) == 0:
        self.projectSessions[message] = []
        pass
    self.projectSessions[message] = self.projectSessions[message].append(self)
    print(self.projectSessions[message])
    self.userjoinedMessage(self.projectSessions[message])
    message = {}
    message["command"] = "STC-openproject"
    message["message"] = p
    self.send_message(json.dumps(message))
```

Then when the user opens a project, he is added to the `projectSessions` list, this however doesn't work (I think) whenever a new user connects to the websocket, he gets his own projectconsumer.

The second way I thought of doing this is to create a managing class that only has 1 instance and keeps track of all the users connected to a project. I have not tried this yet as I would like some feedback on if I'm even swinging in the right ball park. Any and all feedback is appreciated.

EDIT 1:
I forgot to add the `userjoinedMessage` method to the question, this method is simply there to mimic future mechanics and for feedback to see if my solution actually works, but here it is:

```
    def userjoinedMessage(self, pointer):
        message = {}
        message["command"] = "STC-userjoinedtest"
        message["message"] = ""
        pointer.send_message(json.dumps(message))
```

note that i attempt to reference the instance of the consumer.

I will also attempt to implement a consumer manager that has the role of keeping track of what consumers are browsing what projects and sending updates to the relevant channels.

Comment: Why not store the project sessions in the database? In that way, it is persisted and there would be no issue retrieving it even across multiple channels server instances if you ever decide to scale your channels across multiple servers

Comment: @Ken4scholars can you elaborate? what exactly would i be storing in a database. note i started completely new to python, django and django channels about 2 months ago so alot of obvious things might not be clear to me yet.

Comment: From the question, the issue is how to save `self.projectSessions` and have it accessible across multiple instances of the consumer, isn't it? That is exactly what I'm saying you can save in a database. It's a dictionary with project as key. You can make it a table with ForeignKey to the Project model

Comment: @Ken4scholars i understand what you mean now, and yes that would be another way of doing it. allthough i struggle to come up with a usecase where i would prefere the risks presented with adding a database when not strictly required. but if you can formulate your solution as an answer to the question i would be happy to accept it, Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question, the issue is how to save `projectSessions` and have it accessible across multiple instances of the consumer. Instead of trying to save it in memory, you can save in a database. It is a dictionary with project as key. You can make it a table with ForeignKey to the Project model. 
In that way, it is persisted and there would be no issue retrieving it even across multiple channels server instances if you ever decide to scale your channels across multiple servers.
Also, if you feel that a traditional database will slow down the retrieval of the sessions, then you can use faster storage systems like redis

Answer (score 0):

Right, this is probably a horrible way of doing things and i should be taken out back and shot for doing it but i have a fix for my problem. I have made a `ProjectManager` class that handles subscriptions and updates to the users of a project:

```
import json

class ProjectManager():

    def __init__(self):
        if(hasattr(self, 'projectSessions')):
            pass
        else:
            self.projectSessions = {}




    def subscribe(self, projectid, consumer):
        print(projectid not in self.projectSessions)
        if(projectid not in self.projectSessions):
            self.projectSessions[projectid] = []
        self.projectSessions[projectid].append(consumer)
        self.update(projectid)


    def unsubscribe(self, projectid, consumer):
        pass

    def update(self, projectid):
        if projectid in self.projectSessions:
            print(self.projectSessions[projectid])
            for consumer in self.projectSessions[projectid]:
                message = {}
                message["command"] = "STC-userjoinedtest"
                message["message"] = ""
                consumer.send_message(json.dumps(message))
                pass
```

in my `apps.py` file i initialize the above `ProjectManager` class and assign it to a variable.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from .manager import ProjectManager


class ProjectConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'project'
    manager = ProjectManager()
```

Which i then use in my `consumers.py` file. I import the manager from the `projectconfig` class and assign it to a instance variable inside the created consumer whenever its connected:

```
    def connect(self):
        print("connected to projectconsumer...")
        self.accept()
        self.manager = ProjectConfig.manager
```

and whenever i call `open_project` i subscribe to that project with the given project id recieved from the front-end:

```
 def open_project(self, message):

        p = Project.objects.values("projectname").get(id=message)
        self.manager.subscribe(message, self)
        message = {}
        message["command"] = "STC-openproject"
        message["message"] = p
        self.send_message(json.dumps(message))
```

as i said i in no way claim that this is the correct way of doing it and i am also aware that `channel_layers` supposedly does this for you in a neat way. i however don't really have the time to get into `channel_layers` and will therefore be using this.
I am still open to suggestions ofcourse and am always happy to learn more.